# Selenium crashes Chrome when running from Jenkins

Tags: python, macos, selenium, jenkins

Hi used python selenium for Web Automation and launched that python script from jenkins in MAC.

It will load the Chrome and automation goes for some extent and get error message as

> "Aw Snap" page comes up a few steps into the first test

How to fix it

Comment: have you seen this? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TTjslsIqjyY

Comment: is there any other way to fix it